# question about norms and convex set

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Suppose $\overline{B}(0;1) = \{ x \in X : ||x|| \leq 1 \}$ is the closed unit ball on a vector space $X$. MY question is: is the following true?

If $\overline{B}(0,1) $ is not  convex, then $|| \cdot || $ does not define a norm on $X$.

MY question arises, because I am trying to show that $\phi(x) = ( \sqrt{|x_1|} + \sqrt{|x_2|} )^2 $ does not define a norm on the space $X = \{ (x_1,x_2) : x_i \in \mathbb{R} \} $. So, if the above is true, then if can show that

$$ \{ x \in X : \phi(x) \leq  1 \} $$

is not convex, then I would have that indeed $\phi(x)$ does not define a norm on $X$.

any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks

Comment: Do you know the parallelogram identity? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law#Normed_vector_spaces_satisfying_the_parallelogram_law

Comment: yes, but I would like to use the method outline in my question.

Answer (score 0):

*Let $(V,\mid\mid\cdot\mid\mid)$ be a normed vector space over $\mathbb{R}$; then the closed unit ball $\overline{B}(0 , 1)$ is convex.*

---

Proof:
Clearly $\overline{B}(0 , 1)$ is non empty, so let  $x,y\in\overline{B}(0 , 1)$ and let $\lambda\in[0,1]$. Consider $z=\lambda x+ (1-\lambda)y$

Now; $$\mid\mid z\mid \mid= \|\lambda x+ (1-\lambda)y \| \leq \mid\mid\lambda x\mid\mid+ \mid\mid(1-\lambda)y\mid\mid$$
by the triangle inequality. Therefore, 
$$\mid\mid z\mid \mid\leq \lambda(1)+(1-\lambda)(1)=1$$
as $x$ and $y$ are in $\overline{B}(0 , 1)$. Proving that $\overline{B}(0 , 1)$ is convex.

So, if $\overline{B}(0 , 1)$ fails to be convex, then $\mid\mid\cdot\mid\mid$ can´t be a norm.